# Empty SSID nmcli wifi list

Tags: wireless

When I run the command `sudo nmcli dev wifi list`, I get a list of networks without SSID. Why am I getting this result and not surrounding wifi networks?  Should I run a different command?

[image: a photograph of a display with a terminal]

Comment: Your `ifconfig` failed. Why continue? Please copy/paste text instead of linking to screenshots of text.

Comment: I added a screenshot due to the ubuntu is running in another machine. Please, could you provide me with some ideas? thanks

Comment: Please copy/paste text instead of linking to screenshots of text.

Comment: Seems like I have to use sudo to bring the interface up

Comment: Right, using sudo, I don't receive the permission message. However, still, I cannot see the surrounding networks.